# Cannot reset_index inplace on a Series to create a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

When I am trying to reset the index of my dataFrame, it is not working.

```
new = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b','Amount1'])
new['Amount1'] = [0,1,6,7,8,9]
new['a'] = ['sarim',1,2,3,4,'sarim']


df_tf = new[new['a']=='sarim']['Amount1']
df_tf.reset_index(inplace=True)

ret_df['Amount1'] = df_tf
```

Comment: Don't do `inplace`, just reassign: `df_tf = df_tf.reset_index()`

Comment: Maybe add drop? `df_tf.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)` it seems like you're looking to keep it as a Series if you're assigning it back to a column. Probably better to use `loc` though `df_tf = new.loc[new['a'] == 'sarim', 'Amount1'].reset_index(drop=True)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can try,

```
df_tf.reset_index(drop = True, inplace=True)
ret_df['Amount1'] = df_tf
```

or

```
ret_df['Amount1'] = list(df_tf)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could reset index on df then convert to series

```
new.loc[new["a"] == 'sarim'].reset_index(drop=True)["Amount1"]
```